# What is the difference between these two JS functions?

Tags: javascript

I currently have 2 functions that do the same thing, which is a function named numbers that returns true if all the parameters that are passed are of the Number type. Otherwise, the function should return false. The function should accept any number of parameters.

So I did the following function:

```
var numbers = function(numList) {
    for(var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
        if ( typeof numList[i] !== 'number' ) {
           return false;
        }
    }  
    return true;
}
```

But later on, I found this other solution.

```
var numbers = function() {
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(arguments, function(argument) {
      return typeof argument !== 'number';
    }).length === 0;
}
```

The last solution is more advanced though, but I want to know pros and cons of these 2 functions and also, which one is better? Maybe my solution will cause some errors at some point?

Comment: debugging the first one is easier to me because scope is consistent throughout.  Not that issues in this example would manifest scope issues, but more complex examples you could run into them.

Comment: They seem to do the same thing, just with different syntax, and neither is "better" than the other.

Comment: For me too. But I am trying to learn more advanced JavaScript. The first one is my solution to the problem. The second one a more advanced solution, that actually took me 4 hours to understand

Comment: Keep in mind: it's not too difficult to write code that *works*. It's *much* more difficult and much more important to write code you can *read*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first function *shortcuts*, i.e. it returns `false` as soon as it encounters a non-number. The second function always processes all inputs and decides at the end.

The first function is much more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with the first one for three reasons:

1. `Array.prototype.filter.call` looks pretty ugly. `for` loops are much more familiar and therefore easier to read.
2. The first function is more efficient. In addition to what `deceze` said, the second creates a function inside the function. This takes memory. While in most cases the difference won't be noticeable, it still is not very performant.

Edit: If you wanted to be *really* efficient, you could also change this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numList.length; i++)
```

...to this:

```
for(var i = 0, l = numList.length; i < l; i++)
```

That's because the second argument in a `for` loop is evaluated before each iteration. That is: the first way, it's calculating `numList.length` before each iteration of the loop, whereas the second way it only does that once.

Again, in most cases this won't be a noticeable difference, but it's a way of tightening the screws a bit.

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent, but I would use the [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function instead of the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for shorter notation of:

```
let numbers = numList => numList.every(x => typeof x === 'number');
```

Comment: Actually, the `every` function is in the ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262) specification, the arrow notation is ES6

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent, but I would use the **some** function instead of the **every** function for shorter notation of:

```
var numbers = numList => !numList.some(x => typeof x !== 'number');
```

Comment: that doesn't seems to be shorter though :P

Comment: Neither shorter nor faster. Just one more solution

Comment: `but I would use the some function instead of the every function for shorter notation of` i was just being a bit pedantic since you have more character, but you could replace your ternary expression by a simple `!`

Comment: Yes Walfrat, i've just re-edited. Thank's for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I feel a better solution to the first one could be as follows:

`var numbers = numList.filter(function(a) {
    return a !== 'number'
}`

From this you can also see how I'm using the array method `Filter`. The second example you provide is exactly this. It is the **prototype** of the Array method. Prototypes are like classes that you get in other languages. Using prototype delivers better performance as it allows for quicker Object Creation thus a new Object will not have to be created each time the Object is instantiated. A good example could be as follows

```
const User = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
 }

 User.prototype.sayHello = function() {
   console.log('Hello ' + this.name)
 }

 const user = new User('Jack')

 user.sayHello()
```

Using the prototype here makes sure that the `sayHello` method is available in the prototype chain at all times. So each time this method is instantiated Object creation is much faster as it doesn't have to recreate it each time

You should watch a guy on YouTube called FunFunFunction he may explain things a bit better than myself :)